# VFR Sectional Aeronautical Charts with matplotlib (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, raster, matplotlib-basemap

I'm looking for a means to add VFR Sectional Aeronautical Charts (a.k.a. sectionals) to preexisting matplotlib code I have.

In short, can there be a quick and easy means to realize sectional charts with python and matplotlib?  If not, what are the other paths to consider?

Reference: http://robertjliguori.blogspot.com/2016/10/acquiring-vfr-sectional-aeronautical.html

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Quick and easy as e.g. `draw_sectional()`: no. But there are plenty of examples on how to plot (detailed) city outlines, roads, rivers, et cetera. Plotting air space is not that difficult if you have it in e.g. OpenAir format (http://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Hj3.png), but you will likely have to code the plotting routines yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out...

```
map = Basemap(...)
map.arcgisimage(server='http://maps7.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS', xpixels=1500,  service='FAA_Sectional_Charts', layer=0)
```