# Python folium map is not saving

Tags: python, folium

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=13)
m.save('index.html')
```

I'm trying to save the map as index.html but when I run the Python script, I'm not getting any error messages, and I don't see the index.html.  I'm telling it to save to the same directory as the script.

[Folium documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Getting-Started).  This is where I got the code from.  What I'm trying to do is this.  I have a Python script that gets airport information from FAA website.  I'm trying to put that information on a website, but I can't even get the website to create.

I'm trying to do something similar to this [Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976479/vfr-sectional-aeronautical-charts-with-matplotlib-python) , but instead of using matplotlib I'm using folium.  Any recommendations?

Comment: import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=13)

m.save('C://Users//auser//PycharmProjects//metars//index.html')

Comment: I did that, but still no error messages and not saving it.  I tried using // and /, but same result.  I had it working weeks ago, but unfortunately I didn't note it.

Comment: I'm using Pycharm community edition.  I tried python metarsmap.py from CMD and it created the index.html.  How come it works from cmd and not from IDE?

Comment: Thanks @ellanesec for the answer.  Now that I have the folium map, how can I add an overlay on top of it?  I want to add another map.  I would like to add an aviation sectional map from http://vfrmap.com/.  I already got an AP from them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the steps below

```
1. pip uninstall folium 
2. pip install folium
```

finally, try saving your map again.

hope this helps.